# Install Dell drivers automatically with Windows 7 image

Tags: windows-7, drivers, images, deployment

Im working on making win7 images for different model dells. I have all of the drivers on a usb drive and im wondering is there a way to check the updates for all drivers at once and install automatically?

Comment: check Dell for latest driver updates and then install the drivers into win7 images that are ready to be deployed? Or install onto systems that are already deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dell Client System Update](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1960.dell-client-system-update.aspx)

> The Dell Client System Update (DCSU) application provides update
>   capabilities for Dell™ OptiPlex™, Latitude™ and Dell Precision™ client
>   platforms. DCSU is locally installed on the target system. It includes
>   support for retrieving and installing updates for BIOS, drivers, and
>   system software released by Dell.

Dell packages all the drivers by Model too:

[Dell Driver CAB files for Enterprise Client OS Deployment](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/2065.dell-driver-cab-files-for-enterprise-client-os-deployment.aspx)

> ...to simplify OS deployments on those systems with deployment tools
>   like Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager (ConfigMgr/SCCM) or
>   Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT).
>
> System CABs for Venue, XPS, Latitude, Optiplex, and Precision
>   Workstations - are designed for deployment to a single model and are
>   developed and supported by Dell
>
> WinPE CABs are designed to provide required drivers for WinPE to boot
>   a Dell Latitude, Optiplex, or Precision Workstation for the purpose of
>   OS Deployment.
>
> Family CABs are designed for deployment to multiple models and are
>   developed and supported by the Dell TechCenter community.

Comment: DO you know if this can be used to get drivers for a number of dell systems? or is it just for the dell system that the program is installed on?

Comment: individual computers, if you wanted to do groups you could create a msi file with the drivers and use group policy to assign the msi to groups.

Comment: @user214577 do you want to download from dell all the drivers for a particular model? If so, yes you can.... Dell packages them that way for enterprises... added the info to my post.

Comment: This assumes they are not the more common Dimension, Inspiron, XPS, Vostro computers...